# Path error while using Readxml

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an application to read a xml file and convert it to a datatable and there by bind it to a dropdown control using c# asp.net

my code is

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void ConvertXMLToDT()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ds.ReadXml("~/eMAMPreset.xml");
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        Response.Write("done");
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConvertXMLToDT();
    }
}
```

and when execute the code

```
 ds.ReadXml("~/eMAMPreset.xml");
```

an exception occur as below

```
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\eMAMPreset.xml'.
```

I have placed the xml file in the root folder itself
what would be the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get the location of the web application. Else you will get the location of the web server executable (IIS):

```
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/eMAMPreset.xml"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the actual path inside your web application through Server.MapPath

`ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/eMAMPreset.xml"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/eMAMPreset.xml")
```

Comment: This code snippet may or may not resolve the issue, but the answer would be greatly improved by explaining why you have made the change with links to relevant reading or documentation.

Comment: because its code take link from your project directory.